# Validation design issue in combination with nested viewmodels

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm a bit of a beginner in using MVVM in combination with WPF. I can handle the simple things, but I'm currently struggling with the following issue.

Lets say I have a TravelPlan object. A TravelPlan has a Cities object (basically a collection of all the cities that this plan will visit in a specific order).

The Cities are presented using dynamic controls. It shows a dropdownbox of possible cities, a plus (+) and a minus (-) button. Whenever you press the + button, a new empty dropdown list appears for you to choose from.

I've created this with a viewmodel for TravelPlan and a separate viewmodel for a City (see below). I've added validation so that you *have* to select a city.

```
public class CityViewModel : DataErrorInfoViewModel
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<string> _availableCities;
    private string _selectedCity;

    public CityViewModel(IEnumerable<string> availableCities)
    {
        _availableCities = availableCities;
    }

    public string SelectedCity
    {
        get { return _selectedCity; }
        set
        {
            _selectedCity = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedCity);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> AvailableCities
    {
        get { return _availableCities; }
    }

    protected override bool Validate(string propertyName)
    {
        var isValid = base.Validate(propertyName);
        if (MatchesProperty(() => SelectedCity, propertyName))
        {
            isValid = SelectedCity != null;
        }
        return isValid;
    }        
}
```

In the TravelPlan viewmodel I simply use the CityViewModel.

```
private ObservableCollection<CitiesViewModel> _cities;
```

In the TravelPlan viewmodel I also implement the + / - buttons. They simply add or remove a City viewmodel.

This works perfectly.

However, I also want to add validation to see if the combination of cities selected is unique (ie. you cannot select the same city twice). I cannot add that to a individual CityViewModel because a single city has no knowledge about all the other cities selected.

Ideally, I would like to transform the ObservableCollection of CityViewModels in its own ViewModel. I could then add the unique validation to that specific viewmodel. I believe I could also move the logic of the dynamic usercontrols to that viewmodel.

This would create the following hierarchy: TravelPlanViewModel - CitiesViewModels - CityViewmodel where each viewmodel does its specific validation.

Is this possible and is this recommended? I'm wondering how people are solving this specific design issue in a MVVM way. (I know that it is possible to move the unique validation into the TravelPlan viewmodel, but I'm wondering if the scenario I described is possible and a common practice).

Code samples highly appreciated!

Comment: You are correct, you must implement the validation rules at a higher level than the cityViewModel itself if you have mulitple cities for the user to choose.  To do this you may want to implement a ValidationRule at the next XAML layer higher in the view.  WPF will call the ValidationRules and produce the results for you automatically.  Take a look at this class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validationrule(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @user1522548, I'm aware of that. But where do I put that validation? Into the TravelPlanViewModel? Or is it a better practice to create a separate CitiesViewModel?

Comment: Of course we have not seen either the CitesViewModel or the TravelPlanViewModel to advise properly.  As mentioned earlier you have to implement it in the next container up from the location of the CityViewModel.  Typically the proper way to do it is at the closest container to the need.  In other words don't put it a the top level window layer if you can contain it lower in the hierarchy.  One of the tricks I do often is to create containers that implement compositional behavior.  In order words as you mentioned I may create a CitesViewModel that contains all the CityViewModels needed.

Comment: The power of "Containment" or "Favor composition over inheritance" is something that works excellent!  The more I use this concept the better my applications. All you need to remember is this "is the thing I'm dealing with a type of the thing or does it contain a type of the thing.  It it contains a type of the thing, just put it in as a property, or inject it via a constructor.  If it is-a type of that thing inherit it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not unheard of to implement collection view models--just google "CollectionViewModel" to see some examples.  However, if all you're doing is adding validation, I probably wouldn't bother wrapping the collection in its own view model.  I'd just add the uniqueness validation to your root view model, since the constraint seems like it's more strongly related to the `TravelPlan`.

So, yes, it is possible.  I don't know how *common* it is; I personally don't do it, but at least some others have.

Comment: I think you're right in regard to the validation. However, would the commands for adding and deleting a CityViewModel not deserve its own viewmodel?

Comment: They certainly could.  Depends on whether the rules for doing so are general enough to be reusable.